# How can I create a keyboard shortcut to access a specific folder in Finder?

Tags: macos, finder, keyboard, uti

I have been using Total Commander as a file manager on Windows for years. There is one feature I miss a lot in Finder: a shortcut to one specific folder.

Saying I have a folder `~/Downloads`, `~/Dropbox`, `~/Code`, `~/Books`.
Is it possible to setup a customized keyboard shortcut for each of them?

In Total Commander you could do <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>/<kbd>2</kbd>/<kbd>C</kbd>/<kbd>B</kbd>/... etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One option would be to create an Automator service and assign it a shortcut in the Keyboard preferences.

[image]

```
tell application "Finder"
    reopen
    activate
    set p to (system attribute "HOME") & "/Downloads/"
    set target of Finder window 1 to POSIX file p
end tell
```

You could also save the script to ~/Library/Scripts/Applications/Finder/ with AppleScript Editor and use [FastScripts](http://www.red-sweater.com/fastscripts/) to assign the shortcut.

Comment: You do not need to use applescript. Just a 'Get Specified finder items' then add a folder to its list. And a 'open finder items' (open with default) This will do the job.

Answer (score 3):

## Solution using [Quicksilver](http://qsapp.com/)

[image]
[image]
That's it.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to Quicksilver, consider Launchbar. It is a religious preference, so rather than discuss why to choose one over the other, I just wanted to make you aware of both.

Another commercial gem is Keyboard Maestro, which is very much overkill for this sort of job (Automator is the simplest approach, as described by @Lri and @gentmatt), but if you are the sort of person who likes keyboard shortcuts to folders, you will probably find a lot to love in Keyboard Maestro.

Answer (score 1):

[Butler](https://manytricks.com/butler/) rules for this type of thing and MUCH more.

Comment: Could you please add a link? Thanks!